# C++ Vector values changing when dereferencing from another class

Tags: c++, clion, c++23

I need to construct a std::discrete_distribution out of a std::vector from another class. However, everything I get an error

> cannot create std::vector larger than max_size()

I have tried to simplify the code down to basics (also have missed out all the includes since everything else works fine). Also after spending a low time trying to debug have used some console printing to find a problem that I think causes this.

ClassA.h

```
class ClassA.h {
private:
    std::vector<double> weights;
public:
    ClassA();
    [[nodiscard]] std::vector<double> getWeights();
```

ClassA.cpp

```
ClassA::ClassA() {
   
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        initialPheromone.emplace_back(1);
        std::cout << " " << initialPheromone[i]; // TESTING
    }
}

std::vector<double> ClassA::getWeights() {
    return weights;
}
```

ClassB.h

```
class ClassB {
private:

    ClassA *variable;

    void someFun();
```

ClassB.cpp

```
ClassB::ClassB(ClassA *classA1){
    variable = classA1;
}

void someFun() { 

    // TESTING
    for (auto thing = variable->getWeights().begin();
        thing != variable->getWeights().end();
        ++thing) {
        std::cout << *thing << " ";
    }
     // END OF TESTING

    std::discrete_distribution<> firstDistribution( variable->getWeights().begin(),
                                                    variable->getWeights().end() );

}
```

For reference CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD = 23

---

In class A's constructor my cout testing prints 50 1's - as expected.

In class B, something weird prints:
1.14165e-313 -1.15737e+57 1 1 1...

For still a total of 50 values.

Why could these first two be changing?

Furthermore, are these extreme values breaking my distribution because they're too big/small?

Comment: Make sure you have turned on all the warning options.

Comment: C++ is not Java.  C++ returns a copy, not a reference to the vector.  To actually get a reference to the vector in question, you must explicitly state this by using `&`.  If you are using Java as a model in writing C++ code, then this is one of the many traps you will fall into, and that is believing that C++ parameter passing and returning methods work the same as Java (or similar language).

Answer (score 7):

`variable->getWeights()` returns a new vector every time you call it. And if you don't save the vector it is destroyed at the end of the statement.

So with `auto thing = variable->getWeights().begin()` you create a new vector and get its `begin` iterator. Then you destroy the vector. Then you dereference the iterator `*thing`. Then with `thing != variable->getWeights().end()` you create a new vector and see whether `thing` is its end iterator...etc...

Solution: you can make `getWeights` return a reference to the vector in the `ClassA`, instead of a new vector. You can add `const` so the caller isn't allowed to change the vector like `variable->getWeights().push_back(5);`

```
  const std::vector<double>& ClassA::getWeights() { 
//^^^^^                    ^
```